# Javascript "check all" a subset of multiple checkbox groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My checkbox group are in html table. Each row has checbox group. I am trying to put a select_all button in each row of table (which can select all or unselect all the checkbox of that particular row). I used javascript for the purpose. However, select all button checks all the checkbxes of the table. I couldnt find a way to select_all button applicable to only single row. Any idea?

I think the change in javascript can solve this prob, but I am unfamiliar with javascript orjquery.

```
function checkAll(bx) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        if (cbs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="backend.php" method="POST" target="iframe_3"> 
    <table border="10" width="900" bordercolor="green">
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="3"  style="background-color:#7F77AE">DNA</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">seq</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">codon</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)">Select_all</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="3"  style="background-color:#7F77AE">RNA</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list2[]" value="value 3">seq</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list2[]" value="value 4">codon</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)">Select_all</td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, this is a kind of trivial task. You actually just need to query for the `<input>` nodes within you specific `<tr>` node.

```
function checkAll(bx) {
    var cbs = $( bx ).closest( 'tr' ).find( 'input:checkbox' );
    for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        if(cbs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Without jQuery, this would look like

```
function checkAll(bx) {
    var cbs = bx.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="checkbox"]' );
    for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        if(cbs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is now working...Thank you@jAndy code of adeneo also working. But did not tried the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn6ksamc/)

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
            <tr> 
            <td colspan="3"  style="background-color:#7F77AE">DNA</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">seq</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">codon</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" id="check_list" role="selectall">Select_all</td> 
            </tr> 

            <tr> 
            <td colspan="3"  style="background-color:#7F77AE">RNA</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list2[]" value="value 3">seq</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list2[]" value="value 4">codon</td> 
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" id="check_list2" role="selectall">Select_all</td> 
            </tr> 
            </table> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(e) {
                    $('[role="selectall"]').each(function(){
                        // + handle click of select all
                        $(this).bind('click.selall', handleSelectAll);
                        var group_name = $(this) .attr('id')+'[]';
                        $('[name='+group_name+']').bind('click.single', handleSingle);
                    })
                });

                function handleSingle(){
                    var grp_name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var sel_all_id = grp_name.replace('[','').replace(']', '');
                    if( $('[name='+grp_name+']').length == $('[name='+grp_name+']:checked').length){

                        $('#'+grp_name).prop('checked', true);
                    }else{
                        $('#'+grp_name).prop('checked', false)
                    }
                }
                function handleSelectAll(){
                    var group_name = $(this) .attr('id')+'[]';
                    if( $(this).is(':checked')){
                        $('[name='+group_name+']').prop('checked', true);
                    }else{
                        $('[name='+group_name+']').prop('checked', false);  
                    }
                }
            })(jQuery)
            </script>
```

the key is the id of the select all check box is same as the group name without paranthesis